# Codechef-Chef and his Sequence

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, loops

I am trying a solution for the below problem.

link to the problem:[problem link](https://www.codechef.com/problems/CHEFSQ)

**Problem**:
Chef has a sequence of N numbers. He like a sequence better if the sequence contains his favorite sequence as a substring.

Given the sequence and his favorite sequence(F) check whether the favorite sequence is contained in the sequence

Input

The first line will contain the number of test cases and are followed by the cases. 
Each test case consists of four lines: The length of the sequence, the sequence N,the length of F and the sequence F

Output

Print "Yes" if the sequence contains the favourite sequence int it otherwise print "No".

However,I am getting wrong answer.Look into my code

**Code**:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int check(int *p,int *q,int n,int m)
{
    int i,j,l;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(p[i]==q[0])
        {
            j=i;
            for(l=0;l<m;l++)
            {
                if(q[l]==p[j])
                    j++;
                else
                    break;
            }
        }
        if(l==m)
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
int main(void)
{
    int a,*p,*q,m,t,i,n;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        cin>>n;
        p=new int[n];
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            cin>>p[i];
        cin>>m;
        q=new int[m];
        for(i=0;i<m;i++)
            cin>>q[i];
        if(check(p,q,n,m)==1)
            cout<<"Yes"<<endl;
        else
            cout<<"No"<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Provide a link to question please.

Comment: Your code calculates a wrong answer for some input. Try testing it: provide various inputs to your code, and check its output. When you find an input for which your code provides the wrong output, please post it here ([edit] your post to include it). This is called [mcve] - if your post has it, chances are great that someone will be able to answer it.

Comment: BTW, you will not loose points or credit if you make the program more readable by using spaces around operators and semicolons; also use names for variables that reflect their usage.

Answer (score 0):

In the loop

```
    for (l = 0; l < m; l++)
```

`j` may become larger than `n`, causing an out-of-bounds access to `p`. This results in undefined behaviour; all bets are off.